# Detecting uninstall of a service

Tags: .net, vbscript, windows-installer, installshield

I have installed windows service via installshield and when i go to control panel, i can see my windows service, however when i right click on that service, i can see an uninstall option, when i uninstall, my code deletes the service.

> Is there anyway i can detect in the code that user has clicked
>   "uninstall" for this service?

in installshield/via vbscript?

Can i detect whether user clicked uninstall for a particular windows services in control panel?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying. Where in the control panel is the option to uninstall a service? I've never seen it anywhere. The Services MMC snapin doesn't have this screen. Do you mean uninstall the program that installed the service?

Answer (score 0):

The Installer class has an [OnBeforeUninstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.onbeforeuninstall.aspx) (and OnAfter) method. The specifics of how you use this depend on your install builder.

Assuming you're using the VS built-in service installer, you basically [create a class](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/20849/0/) and register it with the Setup package.

Comment: Is it possible thro' installshield?

Comment: I am very new to installshield, i have this link 

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q104327

however am not able to find that onmain method.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 - I'm afraid I don't know much about InstallShield. But, basically, I think you want to run a "Custom Action" via a managed DLL. This link suggests it's possible, if you can find the right GUI prompts (see the .NET Installer Class property). http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpCompProperties.htm

Comment: That's actually a horrible way of doing it.  Not your fault because it's been written in far too many books and blog articles for you to not think it's legit.  MSI's built in ServiceInstall and ServiceControl tables ( supported by InstallShield ) is the better way to go.